# Sed isn't replacing all occurrences of string in file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, cygwin

EDIT: I am using Cygwin. I am unsure whether this is of relevance and it was a detail I missed during writing this question.

EDIT2: Have tried replacing the "TAB" char people pointed out with the RegEx \s which covers spacing chars (spaces and tabs primarily) and this did not affect the expression at all, meaning that it is not the tabs causing the issue, especially since the expression runs once without errors anyway.

So far this script has been causing me a ton of trouble.

I DID have an issue before but I resolved that while I was writing a question here (lucky imo) but this one I've been stuck on for at least an hour now and I've tried varying solutions, none of which actually work or told me something I didn't already try.

I have a rather cool seeming FTP log fetcher script and part of this script replaces the 600MB of errors in this logfile to nothing, essentially removing them. Unfortunately this script also gets rid of parts of other errors too, so I've had to edit it. This is where I'm getting stuck.

Through base research I managed to find out that `sed` could do what I want, and through three hours of playing so far it does most of what I tell it to, minus one thing. One, and ONLY one, of the `sed` statements I have built only replaces the first instance of the string I've given it despite having the `g` modifier attached to the end.

I am working with a test script right now as to avoid potential permanent damage to my original FTP script, and the test script copies over an example file with a few of the errors I need replacing.

Walkthrough of the scripts INTENDED behaviour before showing:
1. Sets a prefix which happens on ALL lines in the file, pretty important part of the script.
2. Copies the example file to a file named test2.log
3. Replace all instances of the UNIX newline char \n with [loll] (first thing that came to my mind)
4. Remove all instances of battle error type 1 and 2.
5. Return all [loll] strings with the UNIX \n for newlines, therefore returning the logfile to its original state minus the errors.

Script:

```
#DTP="\[([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+|latest)\.log\] \[[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\] \[Server   thread/(INFO|WARN)\]: "
echo "${DTP}"
DTP1="\[[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\]\s\[Server\sThread\/\(WARN\|INFO\)\]:\s"
DTP="\[loll\]\[[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\]\s\[Server\sThread\/\(WARN\|INFO\)\]:\s"
echo "${DTP}"
echo "1"
cp test.log test2.log
#cat test.log >test2.log
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\[loll\]/g' test2.log #| egrep -i "" >test2.log
sed -i 's/'${DTP1}'Caught error in battle.  Continuing...'${DTP}'java.lang.NullPointerException'${DTP}' at com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.battles.controller.participants.PixelmonWrapper.useAttack(PixelmonWrapper.java:173)'${DTP}' at com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.battles.controller.participants.PixelmonWrapper.takeTurn(PixelmonWrapper.java:330)'${DTP}'  at com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.battles.controller.BattleControllerBase.takeTurn(BattleControllerBase.java:276)'${DTP}' at com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.battles.controller.BattleControllerBase.update(BattleControllerBase.java:157)'${DTP}'   at com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.battles.BattleRegistry.updateBattles(BattleRegistry.java:63)'${DTP}'    at com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.battles.BattleTickHandler.tickStart(BattleTickHandler.java:12)'${DTP}'  at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_20_BattleTickHandler_tickStart_WorldTickEvent.invoke(.dynamic)'${DTP}'  at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:51)'${DTP}' at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:122)'${DTP}'    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler.onPostWorldTick(FMLCommonHandler.java:255)'${DTP}'  at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:929)'${DTP}'  at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71190_q(DedicatedServer.java:429)'${DTP}'    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:776)'${DTP}'  at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:639)'${DTP}'   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)//gI' test2.log
echo "2"
sed -i 's/'${DTP1}'Caught error in battle.  Continuing...'${DTP}'java.lang.NullPointerException\[loll\]//gI' test2.log
echo "3"
sed -i 's/\[loll\]/\n/g' test2.log
```

I've set them to also run case insensitive checks on the provided strings as sometimes I write with all lower case, however for most of this I copied and pasted it directly.

Sample input:
http://pastebin.com/3KPB33X2

Outputs:
Expected:

```
meow
Test message
WOOF MEOWLOL
```

Actual: http://pastebin.com/pnvDwkxz

It's been killing my mind for a while now because I had this issue even before the other one, except I barely noticed it. I can't find any predictable behaviour in the script, and as far as I am aware it SHOULD be working perfectly fine and giving me the output I expect.

Any help would be appreciated, because as soon as I can get this bug sorted out I'll be able to enter in the rest of the script and replace this with the existing battle-error replacement script in my log-fetcher.

Knowing me it's something small and stupid but I've tried literally everything I came across, including adding the `:a;N;$!ba;` to the start of the bit which isn't working properly (and realising that failed horribly).

Thanks.
~BAI1

Comment: It looks like there's more than one space, or maybe a TAB, before `at`. Try using `\s+` there.

Comment: So to be short, you want to remove `[00:00:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Caught error in battle.  Continuing...` and all the error lines after, isn't it?

Comment: @Barmar, I rewrote the entire script to ensure it wasn't syntax errors before I posted here, including the possibility of the tab/space thing before "at". I double-checked the log and it is actually a tab just prior to "at", and using a tab does not cause issues in the first instance of error removal.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, exactly that. There's three different types of battle error but the larger one in there is the primary one. The third one I can do later once we've found out why this isn't working as expected.

Comment: Also, both and others note that the second expression works perfectly unless interrupted, then misses a step and continues as usual. Example output: http://pastebin.com/bgcBJiTN and what I put in: http://pastebin.com/DrZA8yLS

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
sed -n ':a;s/\[.*Server thread\/\(INFO\|WARN\).*//i;/^$/!p;n;b a' battle.log
```

Comment: Explain how this is relevant when the syntax for catching the [Server thread/INFO] and [Server thread/WARN] already works exactly as expected. My issue is that it's not trying to replace further instances of a specific error (type one, the larger Sed expression) in a file after an interruption, EG: text between the end of one error and the start of another.

Comment: @BAI1: This sed command replace all the script. If It doesn't what you want, try to give a more representative example file.

Comment: I don't want to replace all of the [Server thread/INFO] or [Server thread/WARN] statements in my file. Sorry if what I said might have come across as disrespectful, although what I want is a script to remove all of the errors in my example input file http://pastebin.com/3KPB33X2 but nothing else.

Comment: Intending to edit one of my above comments, I don't want to delete all lines after an occurrence of either of the above two strings. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BAI1: You're welcome. The main problem is that you didn't explain why a line or a substring should or should not be deleted, What is/are the criteria? Your original script is obviously too complicated and is not the solution. A sed command that contains literaly 15 lines, it's crazy. So, if you explain how you know that a line must be deleted or not, it will be possible to help you. Otherwise, you will find few people interested to debug a wrong approach in a long script and that treats a lot of datas.

Comment: There's three types of error in which occurs within this logfile, the main two posted in the main question. The first sed statement turns it all into a single line so I can remove the errors through further sed statements efficiently without touching other errors. The previous script I used, while it did do its job well, it also removed parts of other errors not associated with the two errors I want removed.

Comment: In relation to that I determined that I needed to read the lines after the opening error statement, usually a "Caught error in battle" line. Each error line starts with "at" except for the first two, and there's an unknown number of lines after the error starts and an unknown number of errors per log. Due to this any sort of number-based regulated script can't be used. Lines can basically only be read for deletion if they are definitely part of the error I want removed. Making the logfile 1 line allows for filtering of the errors as a single-line string, which makes it much easier to filter.

Comment: @BAI1: Ok, There is an easy way to do that. Wait a little, I have some things to do now.